# business_type when creating a custom account and French Associations

Tags: stripe-payments

When asking for a token in a custom account creation process, if we do not set `business_type`, it is possible, using Onboarding, to set your Business Type later.

What is the correct answer for an Association in France ?

1. Individual / micro-entreprise
2. Company

Associations can have a SIREN (unique French business identification number). But not all associations have one.
If we choose type 1, we do not have to fill for a SIREN, but then **my question is: will it be a problem later for payouts** ?

Comment: I believe business type is optional on creation (https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_account#create_account_token-account-business_type) but you should reach out to Support for help with this: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Comment: Thank yoiu for your reply, I will write a email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the support. OnBoarding does not provide an option for custom accounts and associations.It is a work in progress.